# group records by day (eloquent) laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

hello my friends i have a problem . i am making a query and wanna get records group By Day . right now **i have done this code** :

```
$pedidosChart =  DB::table('pedidos')
            ->selectRaw(' count(*) as count ,  DATE_FORMAT(fecha_creado, \'%d\') as day , sum( pedidos.precio_total) as  amount ')
            ->whereMonth('fecha_creado', 12)
            ->groupBy('day')
            ->get()
```

**i got this:**

```
  0 => {#1388 ▼
      +"count": 4
      +"day": "15"
      +"amount": 6073.5798950195
    }
    1 => {#1387 ▼
      +"count": 8
      +"day": "17"
      +"amount": 22565.599243164
    }
    2 => {#1389 ▼
      +"count": 11
      +"day": "18"
      +"amount": 13111.219726562
    }
```

and i want getting :

```
[▼
  15 => array:2 [▼
    "count" => 4
    "amount" => 6073.5798950195
  ]
  17 => array:2 [▼
    "count" => 8
    "amount" => 22565.599243164
  ]
  18 => array:2 [▼
    "count" => 11
    "amount" => 13111.219726562
  ]
  21 => array:2 [▼
    "count" => 4
    "amount" => 2910.5600585938
  ]
```

*i got above result because use a foreach (loop) for sorting data* .
*is it possible ? how ?*

Comment: incomplete detail the key 15,17, 18 where they are comming from?

Comment: they are days of each record when records were created ->check select

Comment: 15, 17, 18,  21 is required result?

Comment: FYI: You are not using Eloquent here, only the query builder. Try to run this as a pure SQL - you will probably get a much clearer message. BTW, all non-aggregated columns should be in the group by ...

Answer (score 0):

One quick solution if you don't want to remove the`day` key from actual array.

You can just use laravel collection method [groupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-groupby).

```
$grouped = $pedidosChart->groupBy('day');
```

Other solution would be using foreach loop and setting key as value of `day` and then unsetting it.

```
$grouped = [];
foreach($pedidosChart as $key => $obj) {
    $grouped[$obj->day] = $obj;
    unset($grouped[$obj->day]['day']);  
}
```

Comment: i made that solution in the past  but it is rare the result because it would be a array inside anotther array ,this is resuls:
```  15 => \Support\Collection {#1384 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        0 => {#1388 ▼
          +"count": 4
          +"day": "15"
          +"amount": 6073.5798950195
        }
      ]
    }

Comment: yes man it looks better when is array format, but i don't if know u can check this screenshot
https://imgur.com/a/ffYEdWY
u can see format that got : [day => [ index  =>{values}]
instead i want it was [day => {value }]
i dont know if u understand me want to mean,in  another words i want to sustitute index of array by day value

Comment: which laravel version you're using?

Comment: i am using laravel version 8